# Arba'a Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OU.ORG: On 2 MarCheshvan, Mir Yeshiva was forced to close its doors after 124 years, in 1939.

http://www.ou.org/about/judaism/bhyom/hebrew/marcheshvan.htm

Per Wikpedia: The number of Yiddish speaking individuals in Estonia is 124.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_language

Answer (score 1):

Is it a small matter that 124 is the gematria of "הַמְעַט" - which appears in [this week's Torah portion](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/3191/jewish/Vayeitzei.htm) ([Gen. 30](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0130.htm):15)?

Comment: Yes, I beleive it is.

Answer (score 1):

Both Parshas Shemos and Parshas Emor have 124 Pesukim

Answer (score 0):

Per the Kol Bo Siman 122 - Al HaNisim from Chanuka has 124 words like the Gematria of Yochanan. (I counted and found only 112 words - is there another Nusach?)

The Kol Bo mentions that Tehilim 90 which was said by Moshe Rabeinu upon the completion of the Mishkan in Kislev - Hashem told Moshe to wait and do the Chanukas HaMishkan in Nisan and at a later date there will be a Simcha in Kislev - from Hasem Maon till Al Bneyem has 124 words.